# How to configure nginx to allow connections only from specific React Native app?

Tags: react-native, nginx

I've set up most of what I needed to, including a separate server for my Nodejs backend, which handles all the logic for my React Native app (using Expo).

As it stands right now, my server is publically accessible, meaning anyone can access my protected and unprotected routes, including my health check route.

How can I ensure that only requests from my React Native app will be accepted?

I should probably mention that I've looked online for a solution, but not much came up. The most that I can come up with is just protecting all my routes by checking for a specific header that I set in the app, which is definitely not the best solution. My protected routes that check for a session user are fine I guess, but anyone can still spam even those routes however many times they want.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a separate Auth application and for Nginix configuration you can set up a server like this. Whenever a new request comes into your server you will redirect it to Auth applications where you can check if it is a valid user or unknown traffic only valid users after authentication will be redirected towards your actual app with server configuration route from nginix.
this mechanism will ensure that only valid traffic will bypass your Nginix server to your actual backend server.
In this process your Nginx server will have two separate server objects one for auth and the other one for actual application.